# how to make custom view appear only horizontal?

Tags: android

Hi i have a linear layout and i want to  show my custom view only horizontal but it just does not work why?i have the xml like that:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
  android:id="@+id/ll"
  android:background="@drawable/horizon">
```

but i add custom view on it so maybe there should i set some attributes but i do not know which.

```
MyView mView = new MyView(this,i);
realViewSwitcher.addView(mView);
```

myView.java:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context, int kolki) {
        super(context);

        if (kolki == 0){
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.distspeed);
        }
        if (kolki == 1){
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hxmdist);
        }
    }

    public void setBackgroundResource (int resid){
        super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    } 

    public void onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Path path = new Path();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        c.drawPaint(paint);
        for (int i = 50; i < 100; i++) {
               path.moveTo(i, i-1);
               path.lineTo(i, i);  
        }
        path.close();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setPathEffect(null);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        c.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

}
```

thanks

i mean somethink like angry birds when you start app it flip to horizontal mode and does not flip back while the game is running, i need exactly the same thing.it should retain in landscape mode while the activity is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an extra Layout XML-File for the Landscape mode, you can put those Layouts in the `res/layout-land`-Folder, see [here](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/7/).

Comment: it does not let compile the program [2011-05-16 14:12:28 - TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo]     (skipping index file 'C:\Users\Bladeszasza\workspace\TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo\res\drawable-hdpi\Thumbs.db')
[2011-05-16 14:12:28 - TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Bladeszasza\workspace\TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo\res/layout_land

Comment: You do realize that the "/"-Shlash was a path-seperator? So it's the "layout-land" Folder in your "res"-Folder. Also, the Thumbs.db is created when you use the Windows Explorer to get a preview on your picture. This File can be deleted.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean sorry

Comment: Put the Layout which should be shown when you turn your Device in Landscape mode in your "Layout-Land"-Folder in the (already existing) "res"-Folder.

Comment: I did that and it show me the same error, but i was need to make layout_land folder in the res folder because it do not contains it.

Comment: Yes, it's not created by default. Also try to delete the Thumbs.db File.

Comment: Above you said "if i create layout_land folder", the folder needs to be "layout-land".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need to restrict orientation to horizontal?

[How do you create an app that only allows horizontal orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233612/how-do-you-create-an-app-that-only-allows-horizontal-orientation)

In your application's manifest file, within the application tag, put `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: but it just not work and if i create layout_land folder it does not compile the app...