# Android - Disable vertical layout for entire app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how to disable the vertical layout such that the application starts and runs in horizontal layout only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create an app that only allows horizontal orientation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233612/how-do-you-create-an-app-that-only-allows-horizontal-orientation) and also of [Android, landscape only orientation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408197/android-landscape-only-orientation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to your `<activity>` tag in the manifest for all your activity that you want to be in landscape.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Manifest XML file under each `<activity>` tag specify the orientation as horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

as an attribute to the relevant `<activity>` tag(s) in the manifest.